# Can you pass a TCP connection from one process to the other?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I am doing some network testing, and I am connecting between linux boxes with 2 small C programs that are just using function:

```
connect()
```

After connection some small calculations are made and recorded to local file, and I instruct one of the programs to close the connection and then run a netcat listener on the same port. The first program then retries the connection and connects to netcat.

I wondered if someone could advise if it is possible to maintain the initial connection whilst freeing the port and pass the connection to netcat on that port (so that the initial connection is not closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each TCP connection is defined by the four-tuple (target IP address, target port, source IP address, source port), so there is no need to "free up" the port on either machine.

It is very common for a server process to `fork()` immediately after `accept()`ing a new connection. The parent process closes its copy of the connection descriptor (returned by `accept()`), and waits for a new connection. The child process closes the original socket descriptor, and executes the desired program or script that should handle the actual connection. In many cases the child moves the connection descriptor to standard input and standard output (using `dup2()`), so that the executed script or program does not even need to know it is connected to a remote client: everything it writes to standard output is sent to the remote client, and everything the remote client sends is readable from standard input.

If there is an existing process that should handle the connection, and there is an Unix domain socket connection (stream, datagram or seqpacket socket; makes no difference) between the two processes, it is possible to transfer the connection descriptor as an `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary message. See [`man 2 sendmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html), [`man 2 recvmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html), [`man 3 cmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html), and [`man 7 unix`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) for details. This only works on the same machine over an Unix domain socket, because the kernel actually *duplicates* the descriptor from one process to the other; really, the kernel does some funky magic to make this happen.

If your server-side logic is something like

- For each incoming connection:

  1. Do some calculations
  2. Store calculations into a file
  3. Store incoming data from the connection into a file (or standard output)

then I recommend using `pthreads`. Just create the desired number of threads, have all of them wait for an incoming connection by calling `accept()` on the listening socket, and have each thread handle the connection by themselves. You can even use `stdio.h` I/O for the file I/O. For more complex output -- multiple statements per chunk --, you'll need a `pthread_mutex_t` per output stream, and remember to `fflush()` it before releasing the mutex. I suspect a single multithreaded program that does all that, and exits nicely if interrupted (`SIGINT` aka `CTRL+C`), should not exceed three hundred lines of C.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to output data from a stream socket, or if you only need to write input to it, you can treat it as a file handle.

So in a Posix program you can use dup2() to duplicate the socket handle to the value 1, which is standard output. Then close the original handle. Then use exec() to overwrite your program with "cat", which will write the output from standard input aka filehandle 1 aka your socket.